# Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.core.task.support.ExecutorServiceAdapter

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, autowired

I am really stuck and i need your help.

I am getting the following autowire error

> Could not autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.core.task.support.ExecutorServiceAdapter

could not autowire because he cant find it.
but clearly it is there, I see it in maven dependencies.

what could possibly cause spring to not find his own beans?!

Thank you

Comment: Please show your spring configuration. This has nothing to do with maven.

Comment: what exactly would you like to see.

Comment: I'd like to see where `ExecutorServiceAdapter` bean is declared. Please use `@myname` when responding to me. I didn't get a notification from your last comment :(

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis this is a spring bean... from the spring core package.

Comment: No, it is a class in the spring framework. It is not declared as a bean anywhere. You can't just assume spring will instantiate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to configure an instance of that class to be managed within the spring context? Normally spring will only look for managed beans to auto wire.

Comment: Yes... I am actually migrating from Jersey to spring, and somehow magically this bean does not exist anymore.

Comment: I might be misunderstandng your problem. But if I had a setter for MyMagicBean, and annotated it as autowired, I would also need to have an @Component annotation, or some alternative, on the MyMagicBean class. Or a <bean id=magicBean class="foo.bar.MyMagicBean"/> in a spring context file.  If I don't, spring won't be able to find MyMagicBean to autowrire in.

Comment: take a look at the class. it is under org.springframework.core and is currently working under Jeresy deployment. which means that this class is loaded into the container. but under jeresy. why not under spring